# How is jin jun mei (a Chinese tea) made?

Tags: ingredient-selection, tea

I'd like to know whether jin jun mei (golden beautiful eyebrow, a Chinese tea) is kosher. To know that, I first need to know its ingredients and how it's processed.

What are the ingredients in Jin Jun Mei?
How are the ingredients processed?

Answer (score 5):

According to Wikipedia, [Jin Jun Mei tea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_Jun_Mei_tea) is just a (unsmoked) Lapsang souchong tea or, in simpler words, a black tea. It is considered a black tea of special or extra high quality, but there are no indications that it is produced differently that "normal" black teas.

You might double-check with your religious authorities as the question of being kosher or not is off-topic here, but as I see it, the same rules apply as for any black tea.